# Angular : How Inject html from controller

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, escaping

Something like this:

I would like to inject html from my controller to my scope without escaping it:

```
$scope.results = (typeof data.Clients[0] === 'undefined') ? '<span class="badge badge-important">No result</span>' : data.Clients[0].results+' Result(s)';
```

Comment: Doing any UI related work in controller isn't good. Consider use directive instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't inject html from the controller. This should look like e.g. so in the template:

```
<span ng-hide="angular.isDefined(results)">No result</span>

<span ng-show="angular.isDefined(results)">{{results}} Result(s)</span>
```

In angular, you cleanly separate the template from the business layer.

It is possible to output raw html, but you are going against everything Angular stands for if you do this. You are also making you own life harder.

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="results"></span>
```

Comment: "Going against everything Angular stands for" -- a bit excessive, don't you think? Personally I have a text blob that comes in as Markdown and I need to write out HTML.

Comment: Then you should use a directive to insert it, not a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's not a good pratice to inject html from controller the best way to doing this is

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="results"></span>
```

It worked very well for me